# different solution in Dantzig–Wolfe decomposition decomposition and lingo output? why?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, operations-research

i want to solve this problem , i solved it by lingo and output is :

$z^*=540; X11 =  1.666667 ,   X21=  32.22222  ,  X12 =   33.33333  ,  X22 =0.000000$

when i solved this problem by  Dantzig–Wolfe decomposition decomposition i get $z^*=540; X11=X22=0, X12=X21=\frac{100}{3}$

but in two case ,when substitute solution in $Z$ we dont have $Z=540$ !!

substitute lingo solution in Z we have Z= 535.55

and when my solution substitute in Z , we have Z=533.33

why?

how can solve this problem by Dantzig–Wolfe decomposition,i think my solution is wrong?

$\max z= 8*x11 + 6*x21 + 10*x12+8*x22$

$s.t.$

$ 2*x11+3*x21 <=100$

$3*x12+4*x22 <=100$

$x11+x12 <=35$

$x21+x22<=35$

$X11,X12,X21,X22 >=0$

Comment: The lingo solution is correct, and achieves the optimal objective value of 540 (not 535.55). Your solution is incorrect (suboptimal).

Comment: @Mark L. Stone hello, the lingo output is $z∗=540;X11=1.666667,X21=32.22222,X12=33.33333,X22=0.000000$ ,and objective function is $maxz=8∗x11+6∗x21+10∗x12+8∗x22$ ,substitute lingo solution in Z we have Z=8*1.666667+6*32.22222+10*33.3333+8*0= 535.55 we dont have 540!!

Comment: You must be using a defective calculator. 8*1.666667+6*32.22222+10*33.3333+8*0= 540, as I wrote above.

Comment: I agree with Mark that the Lingo solution has objective value 540. The solution you got by D-W, however, has (suboptimal) objective value 533.333...

Comment: @Mark L. Stone ,prubin . OK ,thanks

Comment: How can  solve by Dantzig-Wolf , I  solved 3 times ,but every time ,j get533.

Comment: In the problem exist 2 set, Assume Constrain 1 be as a set1, constrain 2 as set 2, constrain 3,4 be a central constrain. Please give me help to solved by D-W